# Wi-Fi router gateway IP adding as nameserver IP in resolv.conf only works for Pulse secure VPN connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dns, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and trying to connect Pulse secure VPN with default nameserver entries in below resolv.conf file, but unable to connect, it gets connected for second or 2 seconds and gets disconnected immediately.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Checked /var/log/syslog and it shows like

connmand[1059]: wlo1 {del} route 134.244.29.72 gw 192.168.31.1 scope 0 
Apr 16 21:08:25 ubuntutest connmand[1059]: wlo1 {del} route 192.168.31.1 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 
Apr 16 21:08:25 ubuntutest connmand[1059]: wlo1 {del} route 134.244.218.70 gw 192.168.31.1 scope 0 
Apr 16 21:08:25 ubuntutest connmand[1059]: wlo1 {del} route 194.138.21.32 gw 192.168.31.1 scope 0 
Apr 16 21:08:25 ubuntutest connmand[1059]: wlo1 {del} route 192.94.39.58 gw 192.168.31.1 scope 0 
Apr 16 21:08:25 ubuntutest connmand[1059]: wlo1 {del} route 192.94.39.224 gw 192.168.31.1 scope 0

**but when I add my Wi-Fi router's gateway IP 192.168.31.1 as nameserver 192.168.31.1 in /etc/resolv.conf and restart NetworkManager service, VPN gets connected without any issue.**

I am surprised what making difference this entry, but I think one should not use this workaround as there would be different IP for different Wi-Fi router.

Can anybody help on this issue please ?

Comment: Removing connman package from Ubuntu OS will resolve this issue, but make sure it is not required/being used for other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `connman` package from Ubuntu OS will resolve this issue, but make sure it is not required/being used for other purpose.